# What is the fastest way to read a single line of a large text file in Unix?

Tags: unix

Let's say that I have a large text file with `N` lines. I sample a line number `n` which lies between `1` and `N`, and I want to read line `n` from the file. Is there some way to do this without reading the previous `n - 1` lines?

I could put each line into its own file and call that file the line number, but I would prefer to have everything in one file.

Comment: Unless the lines are all fixed length, or you have a separate index of where each new line is in the file, no.

Comment: Are you looking for a simple shell commad (eg `sed -n ${n}p`), or do you want to seek forward to a position in the file and only read the nth line? ie, what do you mean by "fastest"?

Comment: If you want to do this a lot, your best bet may be to use a database library and store the text in the database, so you have fast random access.

Comment: @NateEldredge Alternatively, build another text file with offsets of each line.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Sure, but then you have to read all the way through your index file each time.  You have to write the code to build and parse that file, and some way to make sure the index is rebuilt if the text file ever changes.  So in many cases, it may save time and trouble overall to just go straight to a database solution, even if it seems like overkill.

Comment: If you know the maximum length of each line, you can build a sparse where each line starts in a known place, e.g. line N starts at off set N*M where M is the max line length.